# How to make my Apex class return or "run" a JSON? using APEX REST

Tags: json, rest, salesforce, http-get, apex

I am using the following code to generate a JSON for a Salesforce custom object called Resource Booking. How can I "run" the file (or call responseJSON) so that when I input the custom URL (in the first comment) it jumps to a page similar to this example web page? https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?json

Here is my code:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/demo/createTask/*') //endpoint definition > {Salesforce Base URL}/services/apexrest/demo/createTask/
global class ResourceBookingTransfer {

    public List<Resource_Booking__c> resourceBookingList{get; set;}

    public ResourceBookingTransfer(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        //getResourceBookingList(); 
    }

    @HttpGet //HttpGet request

    global static responseWrapper getResourceBookingList() {
        responseWrapper responseJSON = new responseWrapper(); //responseWrapper object for API response
        responseJSON.message = 'Hello World';
        return responseJSON; //return the JSON response
        //resourceBookingList = Database.query('SELECT Booking_ID__c, Booking_Name__c, Start_Date_Time__c, End_Date_Time__c, Resource__c FROM Resource_Booking__c');    
    }

    //wrapper class for the response to an API request
    global class responseWrapper {

        global String message {get;set;} //message string

        //constructor
        global responseWrapper() {
            this.message = '';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To just test it - it might be simplest to use https://workbench.developerforce.com. There's "REST explorer" menu in there. Your code should be available under resource similar to `/services/apexrest/demo/createTask`.

Why that url? Read https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm

Once you're happy with this manual testing - you can try to do it from outside workbench. Workbench logs you in to SF and passed header with valid session id in the background. If you want to call your service from another website or mobile app - you need to perform login call first, get the session id and then run your code. There are several OAuth flows you can use to do this depending in what your app needs, maybe start with this one: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm